# Dart // Flutter: How to remove Items from List depending on content of entry

Tags: flutter, dart, sqflite

In my Flutter app, I have a database which keeps track of which items the user liked and which he disliked. I have the function

```
  List finalFavoritesList;
      void queryDb() async {
    final db = await database;
    final allRows = await db.query(TABLE_FAVORITE);
    List finalFavoritesList = allRows.toList(growable: true);
    print(finalFavoritesList);
  }
```

which in my understanding creates a dart list from the sqflite database. Logcat prints:

```
[{id: 0, isFavorite: 0}, {id: 1, isFavorite: 1}, {id: 2, isFavorite: 0}, {id: 3, isFavorite: 1}, {id: 4, isFavorite: 0}, {id: 5, isFavorite: 1}]
```

Now I want to remove every entry, where isFavorite is equal to 0 but I don't know how. This new list should have another name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your question itself has an answer!

Use `removeWhere` function.

```
List favorite = [{'id': 0, 'isFavorite': 0}, {'id': 1, 'isFavorite': 1}, {'id': 2, 'isFavorite': 0}, {'id': 3, 'isFavorite': 1}, {'id': 4, 'isFavorite': 0}, {'id': 5, 'isFavorite': 1}];
  
favorite.removeWhere((item) => item['isFavorite'] == 0);
print(favorite);
```

Output:

```
[{id: 1, isFavorite: 1}, {id: 3, isFavorite: 1}, {id: 5, isFavorite: 1}]
```

Refer: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.9.3/dart-core/List/removeWhere.html

Hope that solves your case!